# what is the scope of 'let' in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, let

I tried the following:

```
  describe "#check_recurring_and_send_message" do

    let(:schedule) {ScheduleKaya.new('test-client-id')}

    context "when it is 11AM and recurring event time is 10AM" do

      schedule.create_recurring_event('test-keyword', 'slack', 'day', '10 AM') 

      it "sends an SMS" do

      end

      it "set the next_occurrence to be for 10AM tomorrow" do 
        tomorrow = Chronic.parse("tomorrow at 10AM")
        expect(schedule.next_occurrence).to eq(tomorrow)
      end

    end

  end
```

I got an error around the scope:

```
`method_missing': `schedule` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). (RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError)
```

Not only for this example but other times, I don't fully understand what the allowable `scope` is for let and for creating instances in Rspec.

What's the use case of `let` here versus just me creating using `schedule = blah blah`?

I guess I understand the *literal* intent of the error: I cannot use `schedule` in `context` only in `it.`  But what's the right way then with this example to put stuff under describe, context, or it and in what way?

Answer (score 7):

`Let` is lazily evaluated which is nice when you want to share a variable across tests but only when the test needs it.

From the docs:

> Use let to define a memoized helper method. The value will be cached
>   across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples.
>
> Note that let is lazy-evaluated: it is not evaluated until the first
>   time the method it defines is invoked. You can use let! to force the
>   method's invocation before each example.
>
> By default, let is threadsafe, but you can configure it not to be by
>   disabling config.threadsafe, which makes let perform a bit faster.

You're getting a method missing here because of this line:

```
schedule.create_recurring_event('test-keyword', 'slack', 'day', '10 AM')
```

It seems you want that line to be evaluated before each `it` block in that `context`.  You would just rewrite it like so:

```
describe "#check_recurring_and_send_message" do
  let(:schedule) {ScheduleKaya.new('test-client-id')}
  context "when it is 11AM and recurring event time is 10AM" do
    before(:each) do
      schedule.create_recurring_event('test-keyword', 'slack', 'day', '10 AM')
    end
    it "sends an SMS" do
    end
    it "set the next_occurrence to be for 10AM tomorrow" do
      tomorrow = Chronic.parse("tomorrow at 10AM")
      expect(schedule.next_occurrence).to eq(tomorrow)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense I think. So i can use let in a before block under context?  I am not limited to just 'it' blocks.

Comment: Should let be used at the describe level only then?

Comment: You cannot use `let` in a before block. It goes in a describe block, or a nested describe block, outside of an example. Code in `before` blocks is running in the same context as the example.